# How to configure VNC in Ubuntu 10.04 server edition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I have found next [instruction](http://lifehacker.com/317125/set-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-four-steps) on how to do that

1. Install packages. Code: sudo apt-get install x11vnc vnc-java
2. Set up a password for clients. Code: x11vnc -storepasswd
3. Open up ports 5800 and 5900 on your firewall
   Run the terminal command:
    x11vnc -forever -usepw -httpdir /usr/share/vnc-java/ -httpport 5800

   and add it for auto-starting in future sessions

   Additionally I have executed

   x11vnc -forever -usepw -httpdir /usr/share/vnc-java/ -httpport 5900

   But no success from my vnc client, although I can ping ubuntu

Comment: Does your server have X installed?

Comment: i am not sure, and probably not, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comments: being a server, it probably doesn't have X installed.

The simplest way to get "everything" would be `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. For a more minimal setup you will need `xorg` and a window manager of your choice; `apt-cache search x-window-manager` will give you a list.

Comment: i did that "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop", but what should i do next. vnc still is not available

Comment: it looks like i have found how to start desktop: startx

Comment: i was able to run x11vnc -forever -usepw -httpdir /usr/share/vnc-java/ -httpport 5800 from terminal and able to use vnc, but how i can set it permanently